# Spring Security with annotations

Tags: spring-security

Why the official spring security sample doesn't work?

**SecurityConfig class:**

```
package org.springframework.security.samples.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

**MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer class:**

```
package org.springframework.security.samples.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

/**
 * No customizations of {@link AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer} are necessary.
 *
 * @author Rob Winch
 */
public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

**And login.html (src/main/resources/views/login.html):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:tiles="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title tiles:fragment="title">Messages : Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div tiles:fragment="content">
        <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Please Login</legend>
                <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">Invalid
                    username and password.</div>
                <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">You
                    have been logged out.</div>
                <label for="username">Username</label> <input type="text"
                    id="username" name="username" /> <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Maven libraries (pom.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-samples-form-jc</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>spring-security-samples-form-jc</name>
  <description>spring-security-samples-form-jc</description>
  <url>http://spring.io/spring-security</url>
  <organization>
    <name>spring.io</name>
    <url>http://spring.io/</url>
  </organization>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>rwinch</id>
      <name>Rob Winch</name>
      <email>rwinch@gopivotal.com</email>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security</url>
  </scm>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-samples-messages-jc</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.30</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
      <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.29</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
      <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/sample</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
  </properties>
</project>
```

The project can be downloaded from [Sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/archive/3.2.5.RELEASE.zip)
And [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html) is the official [Spring Web site](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html)

**Technologies:**

```
JDK 1.7
JBoss 7.1.1
Spring 3.2.5.RELEASE
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Excuse me. I get a 404 error code

Comment: 404 indicates a different problem and not that the example is incorrect. Possibly you cannot deployed the application on the right place or you try it to access over an incorrect URL path.

Comment: I am using JBoss 7.1.1